# How do I create a multi-module distribution?

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

I want to create my own Perl module, but the problem is that it contain multiple `.pm` files. The structure is:

```
lib
├── A_Z.pm
└── T_test
    ├── A.pm
    ├── B.pm
    ├── C.pm
    ├── D.pm
    └── E.pm
```

I used `h2xs -XA -n T_test::A T_test::B T_test::C T_test::D T_test::E`. It compiled only `A.pm`; the other `B.pm`, `C.pm`, `D.pm`, `E.pm` are not considered. Is there any solution to execute all the `.pm` file at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Module::Starter::PBP](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aStarter%3a%3aPBP) instead.

```
$ module-starter --builder=Module::Build --module=A_Z,T_test::{A,B,C,D,E}
Added to MANIFEST: Build.PL
Added to MANIFEST: Changes
Added to MANIFEST: lib/A_Z.pm
Added to MANIFEST: lib/T_test/A.pm
Added to MANIFEST: lib/T_test/B.pm
Added to MANIFEST: lib/T_test/C.pm
Added to MANIFEST: lib/T_test/D.pm
Added to MANIFEST: lib/T_test/E.pm
Added to MANIFEST: MANIFEST
Added to MANIFEST: README
Added to MANIFEST: t/00.load.t
Created starter directories and files

$ tree A_Z
A_Z
├── Build.PL
├── Changes
├── lib
│   ├── A_Z.pm
│   └── T_test
│       ├── A.pm
│       ├── B.pm
│       ├── C.pm
│       ├── D.pm
│       └── E.pm
├── MANIFEST
├── README
└── t
    └── 00.load.t
3 directories, 11 files
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special. Just makes sure all the files are listed in MANIFEST as usual. Both ExtUtils::MakeMaker and Module::Build consider all .pm to be modules to install.